# Limit of the whole part of a number

Tags: limits

can someone please help me with the following proof? I am confused as to how to handle the whole part of a number when it diverges? 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}x\left[\frac1x\right]=1$$

Comment: This can't be right. The function is $0$ if $x>1$. Perhaps you meant $x\to0$, in which case the substitution $y=1/x$ would help. Please edit.

Comment: Yes, I edited it instantly, I don't know why it didn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$
\frac1{x}-1 <\left[\frac1x\right] < \frac1x+1
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've solved it to the end :)

Comment: Glad to be of assistance!